# How to customized the list item height in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I am a beginner to android. I want to display a customized list view which contains a number. I customized my List item height size(android:layout_height="50dp"). But when I run the app it display the size largely which am not given. I don't know how to fix this problem. Could anyone help me?

**activity_topic_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.yuvi.secrectsforhappylife.TopicList">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/topiclist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**titledesign.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/storylist">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topictitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**TopicList.java**

```
public class TopicList extends AppCompatActivity {

        String topic\[\]={"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_topic_list);

            ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.topiclist);

            CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter();
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        }

        class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return topic.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.titledesign,null);
                TextView title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.topictitle);
                title.setText(topic\[position\]);
                return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/storylist">
```

and make changes in your listview also like below

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/topiclist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```